# Trying to get autocomplete list to appear on top of chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I initially built this page using an autocomplete control. If you enter a 'G' into the text field, the list of tickers will appear on top of the chart.
http://www.pikefin.com/phptest/charts/allassets/linechart.php?e=1&group=1&title=US%20Equities%20Indivdual%20Line%20Charts

Then I switched the chart type and now the list of tickers is underneath the chart:
http://www.testpikefin.com/phpdev/charts/allassets/linechart.php?e=1&group=1&title=US%20Equities%20Indivdual%20Line%20Charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your Chart Flash object. Flash object appears above all other objects on the page.

Here are some solutions for your problem:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html

Hope this helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

Change the wmode to "opaque"

I tried this in the chrome console and worked

```
$("embed").attr("wmode", "opaque").wrap("span");
```

I had to wrap in a span to force the repaint